# Login persistence: difference between mobile and desktop

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication

I've an app made with reactjs with a backend in node. I've released a test version of the app in an S3 bucket configured as static website hosting, now the strange thing, I've logged in the app with desktop and with mobile.

In the desktop my login is persistent, if I visit the app and then go outside it and came back after a day I'm already logged. In mobile browser instead I need to login after a few hours of inactivity. The app is the same, there is some different behaviours from mobile and desktop browser?

Comment: Can you share the http response headers when you are setting the session id. Also what library are you using for authentication on backend

Comment: Hi georoot, the authentication working well, I use a lambda script the check a JWT and redux-persist to retrieve the token. I've not any problem to login and use the app, just on mobile seems that the token duration is shorter than desktop